# Surface View border with color is not setting

Tags: android

I want to set the surface view border with color at run time. I am doing like this but its not working

```
//Video View to play the vidoes ads.
surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
drawable.setStroke(5, Color.MAGENTA);
surfaceView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
surfaceView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

When I am settings this then video stop to display.

Please help me to get it work correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can  set background color dynamically and give a margin to image

Comment: Like   image.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    image.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: @YogeshTatwal how to set the color from color name "green". If I receive blue then it should set blue

Comment: first tell me r u getting color code if not than you have to use if else condition and also tell me how many color do you have ???

Comment: @YogeshTatwal I am getting color "green" , "red" etc from web service. If i get the greeen then i need to set it. Is there any generic way to handle this without ifs condition

Comment: try the below code image.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2) int i=Integer.parseInt("Color."+"pass you color here"); and ; image.setBackgroundColor(i);

Comment: @YogeshTatwal I am having one problem when i am setting this on surface view (Border color) then surface view stop to display the video

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32660/discussion-between-android-and-yogesh-tatwal)

Comment: @YogeshTatwal I am having problem in the chat. Please reply here. Pleae read "I am having one problem when i am setting this on surface view (Border color) then surface view stop to display the video"

Comment: paste you log here also

Comment: There is no exception. Its working fine when i remove the border.

Comment: use this surfaceView.setBackgroundResource(i);

Comment: I am setting like this surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);. So it set the entire area to Red. So it stop to display the video. Please help me to set the only the border

Comment: also refer http://javandroidevelop.blogspot.in/2012/09/all-about-surfaceview-android-lessons.html

Comment: you have one tricky solution if you want than you can also set layout color of surface view and set padding from it

Answer (score 0):

you can create border form xml styles and then set to the imageview or any other view.

```
<shape
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="give hexa code of your color" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp" />

    <corners 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

Save this file in the as a drawable in drawable folder. for example rectangle.xml

```
imageView1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle);
```